# Useless Augmented Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Two new tags have been recently created.

[augmented-reality](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augmented-reality)[augmented](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augmented)

Should [augmented](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augmented) be removed or made a synonym of [augmented-reality](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augmented-reality)?

Comment: I for one believe the "augmented" tag should be dropped, to me it seems ambiguous.  I'd prefer `augmented-reality` unless there's some better descriptor than `AR`

Comment: +1 I created the `augmented-reality` tag (from the `augmented` tag), probably best to set it up as a synonym.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[augmented](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augmented) is now a synonym for [augmented-reality](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augmented-reality).